# Speed-up rounded corners in IE 9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a couple of divs at the page with relatively lot of content and `border-radius` (incl. the vendor-specific prefix versions) css property applied. Both Firefox and Chrome can handle it without any problems, but in IE 9 it is painfully slow. Just by deactivating it the page can be made at least 5x faster.

Is there a way to speed it up in IE 9 using some kind of workaround / alternative approach. While I'm aware I could probably use background images and additional markup to simulate it old-style but I'm looking for a less obtrusive solution.

Comment: there is this workaround for IE8 using `behaviour` and a `htc` file, I think it works in IE9 but I doubt it would be faster than the native implementation. http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Parzifal has already mentioned, there are some well known workarounds for creating round corners in IE without border-radius. They are based on attaching some javascript code (via behaviour or expression) to specific classes. This code whether adds some additional DOM elements or adds VML markup.

This approach is recommended in that sense that there are actually no cheaper ways to create rounded  corners dynamically and without using images. Though this approach requires thorough testing and makes further support and development at least a bit more painful.

I don't know how exactly do you profiling and which stage is exactly is bottleneck. I rounded corners slow down, say, scrolling as well, I don't know what to advice.

If it is only issue about loading page - You can load everything as usual, but without round corners at all. Then, in javascript, you can listen DOMContentLoaded and specifying existing CSS rules with round corners.

Say, you have predefined class with round corners, the code will look like:

```
$('.there-should-be-rounded-corners').addClass('and-here-come-rounded-corners');
```

And investigate the question once again. Not sure 100% that this will help, but at least it worth trying.

Comment: actually, it seems to be the paint, not the layout/load because the page continues to be slow even after it was loaded..

Comment: @TomasVana slow in what sense - while scrolling there is CPU overhead or what? If you would edit the question, there is a chance you'll get some useful advise sooner.

Comment: Slow in sense of generally slow if you try to touch anything, scroll. I suspect the repaint is simply taking too long for some reason. Thanks for the tips anyway ;)

Comment: I've observed this as well. It only appears to be significant when there is a great deal of content inside the node with rounded corners. It appears to be the paint - though it is slow regardless of where the repaint occurs. Even if the paint is outside the node with rounded corners.Theoretically border radius has no effect on the layout calculations (at least in Webkit and Opera it doesn't). Incidentally, I didn't observe any major CPU burn during the repaints.